# Button links to page in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently I am working on a website where people could take courses from external websites. On the course page there is a button which would take you to that website. I made a meta_box which should hold an URL and use that URL for the button, it looks like this: 
[link to form picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3x3d.png)

But right now it does not take in this URL which I submit in this form. What part am I doing wrong? Here's my code:

This is in functions.php:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'mp_add_custom_metabox');
function mp_meta_callback( $post ) {
    echo "Add the link for the course button here:<br/>";
    echo "<form method='get'>";
    echo "<input type='text' name='buttonurl' placeholder='add a URL here'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' value='Add'>";
    echo "</form>";
}
```

This is in the course single page:

```
<a href="<?php $_GET['buttonurl'];?>">
    <p>
        <div class="btn btn-primary take-course">
            Go to the course!
        </div>
    </p>
</a>
```

Thank you in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
<?php
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'cd_meta_box_add' );
function cd_meta_box_add()
{
    add_meta_box( 'my-meta-box-id', 'My First Meta Box', 'cd_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function cd_meta_box_cb()
{
    global $post;
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $button = isset( $values['buttonurl'] ) ? $values['buttonurl'] : '';?>
    <p>
        <label for="my_meta_box_text">Add the link for the course button here:</label>
        <input type='text' name='buttonurl' placeholder='add a URL here' value='<?php echo $button[0];?>'>
    </p>  <?php
}
add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it
    if( isset( $_POST['buttonurl'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'buttonurl', esc_url( $_POST['buttonurl']) );
}
```

You can then use the value in frontend like:

```
$button=get_post_meta( $post_id, 'buttonurl', true );


 <a href="<?php echo $button;?>">
    <p>
        <div class="btn btn-primary take-course">
            Go to the course!
        </div>
    </p>
</a>
```

Take a reference to : https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes--wp-20336

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I forgot to mention, i am using a template which uses a plugin called "Namaste LMS". So they made a custom (i think something like posts but i dont know really) and its called "course". Do you maybe know how i can enhance your code so it works with those courses? Here's a picture: http://prntscr.com/epwr7t (if that helps)

Comment: If you want to create you own custom meta fields then that should work.

Comment: Hey Rafin, I tried all this code on my website but right now it does not work. The anchor tag does not get any URL so it seems. Do you maybe know why the button doesnt work?

Comment: check if value is saved or not ? Also $button=get_post_meta( $post_id, 'buttonurl', true ); **$post_id** is that correct varaible i your case that returns an id?

Comment: I checked if the value is saved or not using a var_dump, right now on both sides (front-end and back-end) it gives back "NULL" as you can see here http://prnt.sc/esq7zv . What do you mean by if it is the correct variable for me?

Comment: I found out it's a custom post type called "namaste_course", does this change anything and do you maybe know how to do this with a custom post type?

Comment: after saving your textfield value (i.e. url )in backend; does data gets published in the text box after page load? If yes then data is being successfully saved in database and is picking value from database to show in text field. `$post_id` means the `id` of the particular post. Your code is probably within loop and must reaturn post id. Can you please check if it isn't `null` anymore? And yes the custom post type won't matter cause we are showing our meta field all over the post that includes custom post type as well..